# Relation Satisfied by Complex Logarithm (Norm condition)

Tags: complex-analysis

I was a reviewing a proof for the following criterion:
$$
\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (1 + a_n) \ \text{converges} \iff \sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}|a_n| <\infty
$$
where the $a_n$ are all complex numbers.

The argument seems standard, namely one considers the (complex) logarithms of the partial products. However, I am having issues with one portion of the argument. The book decides to truncate (from the left) and remove all terms $a_n$ from the series so that all remaining terms satisfy $|a_n| < 1$. This is of course doable due to the convergence to $0$ of all terms in the series (only finitely many terms are removed, which does not affect the convergence of the series).

However, I am a bit confused by the reason this needs to be done. The book states that $\log(1+a_n)$ satisfies the relation $\exp (\log (1+ a_n)) = 1+a_n$ whenever $|a_n| < 1$. But why is this restriction needed? Of course, I understand this makes the typical power series expansion of the (complex) log hold. But I thought the complex logarithm was continuously definable on any simply connected domain not containing $0$ (i.e we do not need any sort of norm restriction)! What's the issue?

[image: The photo from the textbook (Stein's book)]

Comment: Why not give us a screenshot of the page?

Comment: @HoldingArthur Sure, one moment

Comment: Please do not use the notation $\prod z_n <\infty$ to say that the product converges,

Comment: @rubikscube09 You can avoid doing this, but you have to be super careful with branch cuts if you do; although the $a_n$ must go to zero, they could spiral wildly around the origin before doing so. We avoid this by throwing out enough terms that we must lie in a given disk. As for why the exponential is used? The property $e^{x+y} = e^xe^y,$ which allows us to convert our product into a summation which we understand better

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have rectified that, thank you.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen thanks for the answer, I understand the idea of the exponential satisfying the group property. I am more concerned about the following: Let us say $z_n$ is arbitrarily large and consider $1 + z_n$. Does the log of this term not satisfy our property? Is the idea that we restrict to a disk small enough around $z = 1$ so that we never cross over into the lower left quadrant and never cross over the branch cut?

Comment: @rubikscube09 You are essentially correct. We restrict $z$ to the interior unit disk centered at the origin so that $1 + |z|$  lies in the unit disk centered at $z = 1,$ which does not contain any of the branch cut of the logarithm (we do not include any points in $[-\infty,0]$; note the right endpoint is in on the boundary, so we need strict inequality)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen great! Thanks so much for talking me through this. Please write up your thoughts as an answer so I can give you points.